# SonarQube Excluded sources for coverage differ between projects

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

today I after a merge I was wondering why we have slight difference in the unittest coverage of the same project, having identical code in both branches.

I investigated the Jenkins jobs first, and the configuration of the SonarQube scan is identical. Then searching a while in the server configuration, if there is anything configured different for one of the projects - also identical and pretty standard what we have there.

Then I looked deeper into the logfiles of the Jenkins job and found this.

Project A on branch A has this coverage exclusions, which reflects 100% the patterns in the server configuration:

[Good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqgUv.jpg)

And then Project A on branch B with the identical source code:

[Bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5GnF.jpg)

As You see all settings are the same except the Coverage exclusions.

Does anyone have an idea why SonarQube behaves like this?

Version 6.7.2 (build 37468)

Thank you,
Andre

Comment: There's too little data to diagnose this. You might want to expand with your exclusion/inclusion configurations, project structure, analysis commands, ...

Comment: Hey I found the problem. In the Jenkins configuration there was an explicit override for this particular job. That's why it did not take the server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In the Jenkins configuration there was an explicit override for this particular job. That's why it did not take the server configuration